# How to Convert Columns to Rows in Sql Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot, unpivot, cross-apply

I have a table like this

[image]

and the result should be like this

[image]

i am little bit confused about Pivot and unpivot and cross apply. can anyone help me from this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pivoting on two columns `(department, [check/uncheck])`. As far as I know, that means you cannot use SQL Server's `pivot` syntax.

One way is to "unpivot" (aka "normalize") `checked` in a subquery. You can then "pivot" (aka "denormalize") the `tools` column in the outer query:

```
select  department
,       [Check/Uncheck]
,       sum(case when tools = 'engine' then nr else 0 end) as engine
,       sum(case when tools = 'oils' then nr else 0 end) as oils
,       sum(case when tools = 'grease' then nr else 0 end) as grease
,       sum(case when tools = 'sounds' then nr else 0 end) as sounds
,       sum(case when tools = 'wapers' then nr else 0 end) as wapers
from    (
        select  department
        ,       tools
        ,       'Checked' as [Check/Uncheck]
        ,       checked as nr
        from    dbo.YourTable
        union all
        select  department
        ,       tools
        ,       'Unchecked'
        ,       unchecked
        from    dbo.YourTable
        ) as SubQueryAlias
group by
        Department
,       [Check/Uncheck]
order by
        Department
,       [Check/Uncheck]
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4389c/2/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PIVOT function to get the result, but first you will want to unpivot the `unchecked` and `checked` columns.  Since you are using SQL Server 2008r2, you can use CROSS APPLY to UNPIVOT the columns into multiple rows.

The basic syntax for CROSS APPLY will be:

```
select department, tools,
  [check/uncheck],
  value
from yourtable
cross apply
(
  values
    ('checked', checked),
    ('unchecked', unchecked)
) c([check/uncheck], value);
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/830b4/8), this gets your data into the format:

```
| DEPARTMENT |  TOOLS | CHECK/UNCHECK | VALUE |
|------------|--------|---------------|-------|
|   Maintain | engine |       checked |     0 |
|   Maintain | engine |     unchecked |     0 |
|   Maintain |   oils |       checked |     0 |
|   Maintain |   oils |     unchecked |     2 |
```

Once the data has been converted into this format, then you can use the PIVOT function to turn your `tools` into columns:

```
select department,
  [check/uncheck],
  engine, oils, grease, sounds, wapers
from
(
  select department, tools,
    [check/uncheck],
    value
  from yourtable
  cross apply
  (
    values
      ('checked', checked),
      ('unchecked', unchecked)
  ) c([check/uncheck], value)
) d
pivot
(
  sum(value)
  for tools in (engine, oils, grease, sounds, wapers)
) piv
order by department;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/830b4/9). This will give a result of:

```
| DEPARTMENT | CHECK/UNCHECK | ENGINE | OILS | GREASE | SOUNDS | WAPERS |
|------------|---------------|--------|------|--------|--------|--------|
|   Maintain |       checked |      0 |    0 |      5 |      0 |      0 |
|   Maintain |     unchecked |      0 |    2 |      1 |      0 |      0 |
| Operations |       checked |      1 |    2 |      1 |      5 |      0 |
| Operations |     unchecked |      0 |    1 |      2 |      1 |      2 |
```